# Responsive Adsense Unit Implementation in Bootstrap Website Sidebar

Tags: asynchronous, ads, adsense

How to use Responsive Adsense Unit (Asynchronous Ad Code) in the Bootstrap responsive website sidebar? When mobile is opening the sidebar of our website will be lost and it using @media and use display:none which are not allowed to be used along with Adsense. How to use Adsense in Bootstrap responsive sidebar that do not violate the rules of Adsense? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there someone who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Google has a responsive ad unit that is now in BETA, so it might not be available to all publishers. There is a great writeup of how it can be used [here](http://exisweb.net/using-google-adsense-async-tags-for-responsive-design). And you can also learn how to set them up from the official [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893#adv).

The following snippet will create an ad that runs asynchronously and automatically fills in the size of its container.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- responsive_homepage -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:block"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234"
    data-ad-slot="5678"
    data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Do note that it doesn't automatically resize to fit the container if the container resizes. I guess that is a limitation of using this, and it really can't be fixed without violating the TOS.

Comment: I noticed that in the same [documentation](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893#hide) they show using media queries to change the size of the ad. That should handle the case of "automatically resize" and not violate the TOS since they are showing it in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be really helpful to take a look at your website to understand better what problem you're facing.

Don't know if this helps, but in my case what I did was placing the Ad code inside a `<div class="span12">` that is also inside a `<div class="row">`. This worked for me for placing an horizontal ad and having it centered too.

This is the page where I have that horizontal ad -> http://www.espaciodigital.mx/

Now, if you want to place the Ad code on a side bar, do the same as above, but split the page using, say, `<div class="span3">` for the side bar and `<div class="span9">` for the rest of the page.

I did that in the following page, where the square ads are on the left -> http://www.espaciodigital.mx/quienes_somos.html

Both ads work fine when seen in a mobile device. Hope that helps!